# Jquery is not working in the simple html page

Tags: jquery, html

Here this is the simple html registration page.
My form is in one division. When we will click on start button at that time my form division need to hide and new chatpage division need to visible.
I'm making chat website using node js , socket.io and jquery. 
Right now I'm using that html page using node js server. Everythings going perfect but when I pressed start button, my new division is not displaying as well old division is not hiding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Telepathy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        // socket = io("http://localhost:11000/");

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#b1').click(function(){
                console.log("Inside.");
                $('#regi').hide();
                $('#btn_class').hide();
                $('#chatpage').show();
            });
        });

        function setUsername() {
            console.log("Inside the function.");    
            };
    </script>
</head>

<body background="edit3.jpg" style="margin: 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <div id="regi" class="regi">
        <form action="" id="Registration" method="">
            <center>
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" id="shadow1">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><h1 class="regi_name" style="font-family: TheBlacklist; padding-bottom: 3.5%;font-size: 55px; color: black;"><u>User Details</u></h1></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 6%;"><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name"></td>

                        <td rowspan="2"></td>

                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 6%;"><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 6%;"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter MailID"/></td>

                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 6%;"><input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter Age"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 8%;">
                            <select name="city" id="city">
                                <optgroup label="Country"></optgroup>
                                <option value="uk">UK</option>
                                <option value="usa">USA</option>
                                <option value="india">India</option>
                                <option value="russia">Russia</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td><button id="b1" class="input_btn" onclick="setUsername()" style="padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 8%;">Start</button></td>

                        <td style="padding-top: 2%; padding-right: 25%; padding-bottom: 8%;">
                            <select name="gender" id="gender">
                                <optgroup label="Gender"></optgroup>
                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="chatpage" style="width: 20%; height: 80%; border: 2px solid black; display: none;">
        <h2>Peoples</h2><hr>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: `$('chatpage')` and `regi` wrong selectors

Comment: You miss some '#' at your ID selectors.

Comment: still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#b1').click(function(){
                console.log("Inside.");
                $('#regi').hide(); /// # missed
                $('#btn_class').hide();
                $('#chatpage').show();/// # missed
            });
        });
```

You have missed # for id selector here.